# Why would it be dangerous for a host to reach The Forge and get all the guest data?

Tags: plot-explanation, westworld-tv

In HBO's *Westworld* S2E9, Bernard says that in addition to The Cradle, which contains all the hosts' personalities, there is a digital repository called The Forge which contains all the guests' personalities.  (A tech says that the operators of the park are "replicating their cognition".) Bernard implies that it could be disastrous if a host reaches The Forge. "Imagine what one host could do with that trove of information."

I'm having trouble imagining anything terrible.  What is Bernard insinuating?

Comment: We don't know...that hasn't been revealed yet....but if the hosts have access to everything the real people have **ever** thought....that's a bucketload of power right there.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks. That danger has been insinuated in the last couple of episodes, and I was starting to worry that I didn't understand something that was clear to other viewers.

Answer (score 5):

In episode 10, we are told by

> the system controlling The Cradle (represented by an avatar of Logan)

that:

> "You told me to offer the hosts the accumulated wisdom of dissecting the human psyche a hundred million times over. In short, a competitive advantage. A way to understand her enemy. Their world is not for the faint of heart, Bernard. It's winner take all. The hosts are unlikely to survive out there. But armed with this knowledge she might."